# R Calculate weighted moving average using movavg() from pracma pkg within group_by and summarise()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure there's a way to do this by writing a function in a loop, but the movavg() function is exactly what I want to do, I just can't figure out how to apply it across groups in a dataframe.

The data set is large, but I'm trying to take a few columns (say,

```
data <- c("Species", "Tonnes", "Year")
```

and group all the rows (Tonnes) for each species for each year (there will be hundreds of rows for each Species for each Year), then calculate the weighted moving average for the 10 consecutive years. So instead of summarise(mean = mean(Tonnes)), I'd have

```
data %>% 
group_by(Species, Year) %>%
summarise(wma = movavg(x = Tonnes, n = 9, type = "w"))
```

For the movavg() function, x = time series as numeric vector, n = backward window length (so I think 9 years since I have 10 years of data), and type would be "w" for weighted moving average. But I can't figure out an efficient way to get x and n to refer to the grouped variables.

Any help would be much appreciated!

A sample of the data:

```
dput(sample)

structure(list(Species = c("Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
"Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
"Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
"Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
"Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", 
"Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", 
"Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", 
"Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", 
"Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", 
"Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", 
"Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", 
"Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
"Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica"
), Year = c(2011, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015), Country = c("Australia", "Australia", "Congo Rep", "Australia", 
"Congo Rep", "Cuba", "Australia", "Congo Rep", "Cuba", "Australia", 
"Congo Rep", "France", "Iceland", "Norway", "UK", "Iceland", 
"Norway", "UK", "Iceland", "Norway", "UK", "Iceland", "Norway", 
"UK", "France", "Norway", "UK", "Bahamas", "Cuba", "Bahamas", 
"Cuba", "Bahamas", "Colombia", "Cuba", "Bahamas", "Cuba", "Bahamas", 
"Colombia", "Cuba", "Belgium", "France", "Portugal", "Spain", 
"Belgium", "France", "Portugal", "Spain", "UK", "Belgium", "France", 
"Portugal", "Spain", "UK", "Belgium", "France", "Portugal", "Spain", 
"UK", "Belgium", "France", "Portugal", "Spain", "UK", "France", 
"Iceland", "Ireland", "Spain", "UK", "France", "Iceland", "Ireland", 
"Spain", "UK", "France", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Spain", "UK", 
"France", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Spain", "UK", "France", "Ireland", 
"Spain", "UK"), Tonnes = c(106.05352, 156.34223, 126.58993, 186.88017, 
99.93942, 2.11171, 141.38148, 76.62019, 1.05582, 139.68761, 68.84715, 
1.01059, 122.28238, 51.54047, 1.01059, 146.53669, 21.22253, 4.04238, 
154.62159, 16.16959, 1.01061, 221.32109, 13.4511, 1.01058, 0.10106, 
11.40965, 1.48557, 123.76517, 31.19285, 75.46656, 26.16171, 92.57231, 
0.20119, 13.08084, 148.92064, 25.15554, 53.32971, 0.20118, 25.15551, 
121.27182, 45.47698, 41.43453, 38.40273, 127.33538, 55.58288, 
31.32855, 21.22261, 4.04233, 102.07043, 59.62533, 30.31795, 11.11656, 
27.28616, 85.90087, 82.86908, 29.30735, 5.05297, 38.40275, 110.25632, 
60.06995, 21.18214, 3.52698, 44.86048, 184.93939, 17.18016, 8.08486, 
60.63577, 90.9538, 171.80171, 21.22261, 7.07419, 56.59356, 62.65707, 
158.66387, 37.39215, 3.03183, 32.33914, 85.90084, 169.78059, 
14.1483, 2.02121, 18.19081, 55.58289, 195.41931, 2.99138, 12.89521, 
26.33628)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -87L), vars = c("Species", "Year"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1:2, 3:5, 6:8, 9:10, 11:14, 15:17, 18:20, 21:23, 24:26, 
    27:28, 29:30, 31:33, 34:35, 36:38, 39:42, 43:47, 48:52, 53:57, 
    58:62, 63:67, 68:72, 73:77, 78:82, 83:86), group_sizes = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    Species = c("Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
    "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", 
    "Argyrosomus hololepidotus", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", 
    "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Dipturus batis", "Epinephelus striatus", 
    "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", "Epinephelus striatus", 
    "Epinephelus striatus", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
    "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", "Leucoraja circularis", 
    "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica", 
    "Leucoraja fullonica", "Leucoraja fullonica"), Year = c(2011, 
    2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 
    2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2011, 
    2012, 2013, 2014, 2015)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), vars = c("Species", "Year"), drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: can you provide sample data with `dput()`?

Comment: Sure, good point. Plus I hadn't used dput() before - very useful, thanks

Comment: Did my answer not solve your problem? If not, would you tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. The main difference is that this is summarizing down to the level that you want to run the moving average on first and then creating the moving average.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Species, Year) %>% 
  summarise(Tonnes = sum(Tonnes, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(Year) %>% #Just in case the years were out of order because the movavg assumes chronological order
  mutate(Tonnes_ma = movavg(Tonnes, 3, "w")) #Calculating weighted moving averages
```

I used 3 as `n` here because I only had 5 years of data.

Comment: Apologies for the slow response, was in the field without internet -Thanks for the answer @StevenK, that works! I didn't realize movavg assumes chronological order, and that makes sense to first summarise then mutate.